# Getting a list of objects from mongodb with a filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I am rather new to c# and MongoDb in particular. I have a method `GetAllTickets()` that returns a `List<Ticket>` with all entries of a MongoDb collection called "tickets". I want to be able to only get the entries with a certain filter from the collection in a different method called `GetTicketsWithStatus(Status status)` (where Status is an enum). How can I do this?

I have tried `List<Ticket> tickets = collectionOfTickets.Find(x => x.ticketStatus == status).ToList<Ticket>();` (where `collectionOfTickets` is an `IMongoCollection<Ticket>` but that doesnt get any objects in the List. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: `GetAllTickets()` uses `List<Ticket> tickets = collectionOfTickets.AsQueryable().ToList<Ticket>();` and it fills in the List properly. It's only when I try to use a filter that everything breaks and the list is not filled in.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document and the value of the `status` enum that you're passing in? Basically have we confirmed that you are appropriately comparing values/types with the query?

Comment: A sample document from mongodb:

_id: 634b34404c2f92e01c0696bc
employeeId: 3
category: "login"
status: "open"
description: "lost my login credentials"
priority: "low.

status enum:
`public enum Status {Open, Closed, Unresolved}`

Comment: Sorry if this is silly and I'm missing something obvious, but is `x.ticketStatus` supposed to correspond with the `status` field in the document?

Comment: yeah, so for example if `status = Status.Open` then I want only the documents with `status:open:` to appear

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is that both the field _name_ and the _value_ have to match. As far as I can tell, `status` and `ticketStatus` are not the same thing. Nor are `"open"` and `"Open"`. Can you double check that the query you are passing actually matches a document?  See [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iXjEB00ULN8), noting that the first document (from your comment) does **not** match the query (which I believe I've copied over correctly).

Comment: I think i see what you mean. On my query I was checking for the enum value, but the document value is a string. How would i then make a query in c# that would only give me back the documents where `status:open`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, if someone else has this problem in the future.

First of all, my Ticket model had enums in them, which at first I had (wrongly) saved as strings in mongoDb, then saved those strings in the model, then used methods to transform those strings into enums. I just turned all strings in mongodb into ints and saved the numerical position of the enum in the mongodb doc. Much easier to translate into enum, and makes the Linq expression above work, so it got solved.

Second of all, I tried using Builders to create a filter variable, but for some reason my Find() method would not accept that filter.

Overall, the problem lied in the way I had stored enum values in mongoDb, and how i was translating them on my model